# App Store Connect Api - Average users rating

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I'd like to get the average rating of my app using the App Store Connect API.
I'm calling the api url `https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/xxxx/customerReviews?sort=-createdDate` and I can get the list of my reviews with the ratings, but I'd also like to get the rating of users who didn't leave any review.
Or I would be happy with the average rating.
Is this information accessible with the API?

Comment: hi @vincent, me too looking for the same solution from App Store Connect API. I do get the result but the averageUserRating is always zero. Are you able to get the result so far?? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use API that is used by [App Store Marketing Tools](https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app-store) site. See this Python code for url requesting first 5 apps matching your app name:

```
def url(self):
    params = {
        'types': 'apps,app-bundles', 
        'term': 'myAwesomeAppName',
        'limit': '5',
        'platform': 'iphone',
        'additionalPlatforms': 'iphone,mac,appletv,ipad,watch,web'
    }
    encoded = parse.urlencode(params)
    country = 'US'
    return 'https://tools.applemediaservices.com/api/apple-media/apps/' + country + "/search.json?"+ encoded
```

Resulting JSON will include number of rating and average value in the:

```
 apps.data[].attributes.userRating.ratingCount
 apps.data[].attributes.userRating.value
```

part of the JSON dict.

Make sure you set request headers as if it was requested by App Store Marketing Tools site:

```
header = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
          'Referer': 'https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app-store',
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```